# how do you simplify $ 5 \mathbb{Z} / 15 \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I mean I know that $ \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}_n$,
is there something like it for $ 5 \mathbb{Z} / 15 \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to 5\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ defined by
$$
f(x)=5x+15\mathbb{Z}
$$
Can you determine its kernel and apply the homomorphism theorems?

Comment: I know what is a kernel but I don't how to calculate in this case.

Comment: @JoséMarín When is $5x\in 15\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: when $x$ of the form  $3y$

Comment: @JoséMarín Right. Now can you finish?

Comment: No, I'm lost, sorry.

Comment: @JoséMarín If $f\colon G\to G'$ is a surjective group homomorphism, then $G'\cong G/\ker f$.

Comment: ok ok, the kernel of $f$ are the multiples of three? ${s: s=3r}$ so $Z/ker f$ = $Z/3Z = Z_3 ? $

Comment: @JoséMarín Yes.